# h2 element pushing other h2 and div down. two divs, two headers, and they're wrapped within a parent div

Tags: html, css

I have two divs ".left-panel" and ".right-panel" wrapped inside of a parent element which is a div called ".container". Everything was working great, I had the two panels aligned in the middle, and then I decided to add two h2 headers for the panels and the h2 elements are pushing each other down. How can I get the h2 elements in the same line? I've tried floating them, setting their width, margin, padding, display style... I looked at other answers, but I think mine is different because it's wrapped within divs and within the .container div! In my screenshot it shows the h2 element is spanning the whole row, I want both h2 elements in that same line as headers for the two divs. All help is appreciated, thank you!
[image: h2 element pushing .right-panel and other h2 down]

HTML Code

```
`<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>

<title>Remember Your Diet</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

</head>

<body>

<div class="main-wrapper">
    <header class="main-header">
        <h1 id="main-logo"><a href="#"> Food </a></h1>

        <ul id="main-nav">

            <li> <a href="#">How Much </a></li>
            <li> <a href="#">Nutrition </a></li>
            <li> <a href="#">How Often </a></li>

        </ul>

    </header>

<div class="container">
<br>
<h2 id="left-header">Food Source</h2>
    <div class="left-panel">
    <p> The first key to keeping the tracked changes with the text being copied is to make sure the “Track Changes” feature is turned off. To do this, click the “Review” tab on the ribbon. If the “Track Changes” button in the “Tracking” section is highlighted in blue, the “Track Changes” feature is on. Click the lower-half of the “Track Changes” button and select “Track Changes” from the drop-down menu. The “Track Changes” button should not be highlighted when the feature is off</p>



    </div>

<h2 id="right-header">Nutritional Facts</h2>
    <div class="right-panel">
        <p> The first key to keeping the tracked changes with the text being copied is to make sure the “Track Changes” feature is turned off. To do this, click the “Review” tab on the ribbon. If the “Track Changes” button in the “Tracking” section is highlighted in blue, the “Track Changes” feature is on. Click the lower-half of the “Track Changes” button and select “Track Changes” from the drop-down menu. The “Track Changes” button should not be highlighted when the feature is off</p>



    </div>

    <div class="current-day">
        <p> Today is November 10th, 2015

    </div>

</div>







</div>
</body>
</html>`
```

CSS code below

```
    body {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: green;
}

header {
    margin-top: -8px;
    margin-left: -10px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: darkgrey;
    width: 100%;
}

#main-logo,
#main-nav,
#main-nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

#main-logo,
#main-nav li {
    border-radius: 5px;
    list-style-type: none;
}

#main-logo {
    background-color: forestgreen;
    margin-right: 30px;
}

#main-nav li {
    background-color: gold;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

#main-logo a,
#main-nav li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
}

#main-logo a {
    padding: 10px 20px;
    color: gold;
}

#main-nav li a {
    color: forestgreen;
    padding: 20px 40px;
}

.container {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 550px;
}

#left-header {
    max-width:40%;
    margin-left: 3%;
    color: black;
    padding: 0px;
}

#right-header {
    max-width:40%;
    margin-left: 10%;
    color: black;
    padding: 0px;
}

.left-panel {
    border: 2px solid black;
    width: 40%;
    min-height: 300px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 3%;
    background-color: gold;
}

.right-panel {
    border: 2px solid black;
    width: 40%;
    min-height: 300px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left:10%;
    background-color: gold;

}

.current-day {
    width: 40%;
    margin-left: 2.5%;
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate more about the final result you want? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out! I moved the "#right-header" before the ".left-panel" and then set both h2 elements to inline-block which allowed me to customize their width and margin! Here is the website and what the code looks like!

[image: h2 elements in same row]

HTML

```
    <div class="container">
<br>
    <h2 id="left-header">Food Source</h2>
    <h2 id="right-header"> Nutriton Facts </h2>

    <div class="left-panel">
    <p> The first key to keeping the tracked changes with the text being copied is to make sure the “Track Changes” feature is turned off. To do this, click the “Review” tab on the ribbon. If the “Track Changes” button in the “Tracking” section is highlighted in blue, the “Track Changes” feature is on. Click the lower-half of the “Track Changes” button and select “Track Changes” from the drop-down menu. The “Track Changes” button should not be highlighted when the feature is off</p>



    </div>

    <div class="right-panel">
        <p> The first key to keeping the tracked changes with the text being copied is to make sure the “Track Changes” feature is turned off. To do this, click the “Review” tab on the ribbon. If the “Track Changes” button in the “Tracking” section is highlighted in blue, the “Track Changes” feature is on. Click the lower-half of the “Track Changes” button and select “Track Changes” from the drop-down menu. The “Track Changes” button should not be highlighted when the feature is off</p>



    </div>
```

CSS

```
    .container {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 550px;
}

#left-header {
    width:40%;
    color: black;
    margin-left: 3%;
    display: inline-block;
}

#right-header {
    width:40%;
    color: black;
    padding: 0px;
    margin-left: 10%;
    display: inline-block;
}


.left-panel {
    border: 2px solid black;
    width: 40%;
    min-height: 300px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 3%;
    background-color: gold;
}

.right-panel {
    border: 2px solid black;
    width: 40%;
    min-height: 300px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left:10%;
    background-color: gold;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `h2` also in the panel `divs`.

You can add yellow bg and border to the `p` tag. Or add another inner `div` for giving the yellow bg and border, in case there are more than one `p` tag.

```css
  body {
height: 100%;
background-color: green;
}

header {
margin-top: -8px;
margin-left: -10px;
padding: 10px;
background-color: darkgrey;
width: 100%;
}

#main-logo,
#main-nav,
#main-nav li {
display: inline-block;
margin-top: 0px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
}

#main-logo,
#main-nav li {
border-radius: 5px;
list-style-type: none;
}

#main-logo {
background-color: forestgreen;
margin-right: 30px;
}

#main-nav li {
background-color: gold;
margin-right: 10px;
}

#main-logo a,
#main-nav li a {
text-decoration: none;
text-align: center;
}

#main-logo a {
padding: 10px 20px;
color: gold;
}

#main-nav li a {
color: forestgreen;
padding: 20px 40px;
}

.container {
display: inline-block;
width: 100%;
min-height: 550px;
}



.left-panel, .right-panel {
width: 40%;
display: inline-block;
margin-left: 3%;
}

.right-panel {
margin-left:10%;

}

.left-panel .inner, .right-panel .inner{
border: 2px solid black;
min-height: 300px;
background-color: gold;
}

.current-day {
width: 40%;
margin-left: 2.5%;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-wrapper">
<header class="main-header">
    <h1 id="main-logo"><a href="#"> Food </a></h1>

    <ul id="main-nav">

        <li> <a href="#">How Much </a></li>
        <li> <a href="#">Nutrition </a></li>
        <li> <a href="#">How Often </a></li>

    </ul>

</header>

<div class="container">
<br>
<div class="left-panel">
<h2 id="left-header">Food Source</h2>
    <div class="inner">
<p> The first key to keeping the tracked changes with the text being copied is to make sure the “Track Changes” feature is turned off. To do this, click the “Review” tab on the ribbon. If the “Track Changes” button in the “Tracking” section is highlighted in blue, the “Track Changes” feature is on. Click the lower-half of the “Track Changes” button and select “Track Changes” from the drop-down menu. The “Track Changes” button should not be highlighted when the feature is off</p>

</div>

</div>

<div class="right-panel">
<h2 id="right-header">Nutritional Facts</h2>
    <div class="inner">
    <p> The first key to keeping the tracked changes with the text being copied is to make sure the “Track Changes” feature is turned off. To do this, click the “Review” tab on the ribbon. If the “Track Changes” button in the “Tracking” section is highlighted in blue, the “Track Changes” feature is on. Click the lower-half of the “Track Changes” button and select “Track Changes” from the drop-down menu. The “Track Changes” button should not be highlighted when the feature is off</p>

</div>

</div>

<div class="current-day">
    <p> Today is November 10th, 2015

</div>

</div>







</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/afelixj/wrL6vnye/

Comment: I put the h2 elements inside the two "left-panel and right-panel" divs but don't like the way it looks. My goal is to have the h2 headers above each panel div with the h2 headers being in the same row and the left and right panel being side by side as well!

Comment: we usually does that way..,  to make columns, place all content inside column divs... the columns in this case is the panels...

Answer (score 0):

Put the H2 Elements inside of the div panels.

```
<div class="left-panel">
    <h2 id="left-header">Food Source</h2>
    <p> The first key to keeping the tracked changes with the text being copied is to make sure the “Track Changes” feature is turned off. To do this, click the “Review” tab on the ribbon. If the “Track Changes” button in the “Tracking” section is highlighted in blue, the “Track Changes” feature is on. Click the lower-half of the “Track Changes” button and select “Track Changes” from the drop-down menu. The “Track Changes” button should not be highlighted when the feature is off</p>
</div>

<div class="right-panel">
<h2 id="right-header">Nutritional Facts</h2>
    <p> The first key to keeping the tracked changes with the text being copied is to make sure the “Track Changes” feature is turned off. To do this, click the “Review” tab on the ribbon. If the “Track Changes” button in the “Tracking” section is highlighted in blue, the “Track Changes” feature is on. Click the lower-half of the “Track Changes” button and select “Track Changes” from the drop-down menu. The “Track Changes” button should not be highlighted when the feature is off</p>
</div>
```

Then change the styles in the CSS to remove the gold background and border from the entire div and assign it to the P tag only.

```
.left-panel {
    width: 40%;
    min-height: 300px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 3%;    
}

.right-panel {
    width: 40%;
    min-height: 300px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left:10%;
}
.left-panel p,
.right-panel p{
    border: 2px solid black;
    background-color: gold;
}
```

That is the simplest way.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use the `table` element. Its downgraded but would achieve your aim. Use the `td class="YOUR_CLASS"` attribute and it would work better.